# Htaccess 301 redirect with query string params

Tags: .htaccess, query-string

This is so elementary that you have to ask why it is so complex to implement.

Simply need to redirect one url to another on the same domain, the url contains query string aparams though:

I tried:

```
RewriteRule ^article.php?section=exclusive&id=543 articles/view/4639 [R=301,L]
```

I get page cannot be found - the redirect is not happening. I have other re-directs in the same htaccess which work. The query string params are causing problems, and escaping them also does not help.

Note the id's of the two urls are not the same and therefore I don't want a clever re-write rule which converts from one url to another with the query strings mapped to new params. I just want a fast and dirty mapping from A to B.

**UPDATE**

I tried this it redirects but it is adding my old query string to the end of the new url. How can I prevent that?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/article\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^section=exclusive
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.onlinegooner.com/articles/view/3000 [R=301,L]
```

Input url is: mydomain.com/article.php?section=exclusive

Comment: Query string is not matched in `RewriteRule` pattern, use `RewriteCond` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^section=exclusive [NC]
RewriteRule ^article\.php$ /articles/view/3000? [R=301,L,NC]
```

`?` in the target will strip off previous query string.